# Finding a value in a function represented environment

Tags: sml, ml, mosml

When it came to finding a value in a bst env all I had to do was compare the value I was looking for with the root value at a node

```
type 'a tenv = (name * 'a) btree

exception NotFound of name
fun find compare name Leaf = raise NotFound name 
| find compare name (Node (lt, (key, value), rt)) = 
  case compare(name, key) of
    LESS => find compare name lt
  | GREATER => find compare name rt
  | EQUAL => value
```

But in a function represented env instead of a bst with nodes and leafs the  find function is of type

```
name * 'a fenv -> 'a
```

and

```
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a
```

I get the general idea of the function but I'm confused as to how I would traverse the environment looking for the name. Bst has a node and a tree like structure. Can someone just give an explanation if possible?

*EDITED IN*

My working implementation is as such

```
exception NotFound of name
val Empty = fn name => raise NotFound name

fun Find(name, env) = env name

fun Bind(name, data, rho) = fn key => if key = name then data else rho 
key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So an environment is now represented as a function that takes a name and either returns its value in the environment or raises an exception.
This function is going to be a composition of functions, and you "traverse" it by applying functions that represent older environments.
(This sounds more complicated than it is, but it can take a while to wrap your head around it.)

You can create the empty environment by writing a function that takes a name and raises an exception:

```
val empty = fn n => raise NotFound n
```

Finding things is much shorter than a tree lookup, since the environment already is that function:

```
fun find n env = env n
```

What remains is insertion:

```
fun insert (key, value) env = ... what?
```

It has to be a function that takes a name, since that's what an environment is

```
fun insert (key, value) env = fn n => ... what?
```

If `n` is the same as `key`, that function should return `value`:

```
fun insert (key, value) env = fn n => if n = key then value else ... what?
```

`n` might be found in the rest of the environment, so we apply that function in order to look for it there:

```
fun insert (key, value) env = fn n => if n = key then value else env n
```

And that's, as they say, it.

In a sense, the "traversal" code has moved from the lookup function to the insertion function.

Test:

```
- val env = insert ("hi", 23) empty;
val env = fn : string -> int
- find "hi" env;
val it = 23 : int
- find "hello" env;

uncaught exception NotFound
  raised at: ...
- val env2 = insert ("hello", 999) env;
val env2 = fn : string -> int
- find "hello" env2;
val it = 999 : int
- find "hi" env2;
val it = 23 : int
```

As you can see, representing things as functions can be extremely compact.

---

In order to see what's happening, let's expand the first example:

```
val env = insert ("hi", 23) empty
```

Which is the same as (expanding the definition of `insert`):

```
val env = fn n => if n = "hi" then 23 else empty n
```

Successful lookup:

```
find "hi" env
```

is

```
env "hi"
```

which is

```
(fn n => if n = "hi" then 23 else empty n) "hi"
->
if "hi" = "hi" then 23 else empty n
-> 
23
```

Failure:

```
find "hello" env
->
(fn n => if n = "hi" then 23 else empty n) "hello"
->
if "hello" = "hi" then 23 else empty "hello"
->
empty "hello"
->
raise NotFound "hello"
```

---

Exception-handling example:

If you don't handle the exception, you will get an "uncaught exception" error, as in the example above.

You need to handle the exception in the code that uses `find`.
A trivial example:

```
fun contains n env = let val _ = find n env
                     in true
                     end
                     handle NotFound nm => false


- contains "hello" env;
val it = false : bool
- contains "hi" env;
val it = true : bool
```

Comment: molbdnilo thank you so much after 4 hours of trying different methods and reading different explanations yours made much more sense.

Comment: Sorry but im getting errors when find cant find a name in a given env so i rewrote mine to be as the following (edited in my original post) and yet I still error can you possibly tell me if I am checking the error case wrong

Comment: @laughingllama42 You shouldn't do any pattern matching on anything.

Comment: but then how would I check for if name is not found in an env in the find function?

Comment: You don't need to check – the exception will be thrown when the chain of function calls reaches the `empty` function. The three lines of code in this answer is a complete implementation.

Comment: Oh I see but I get an error when running on this test case    find("c", Bind ("b", 2, Bind ("a", 1, Empty))), FR_NotFound "c")      my current implementation is edited in

Comment: @laughingllama42 You'll need to be more specific than "I get an error".

Comment: Sorry but say also in this test case find("b", Bind ("a", 1, Empty))  the result is supposed to be notfound b but instead my code doesnt raise an error and outputs an uncaught exception error

Comment: If you don't catch (I think ML calls it "handle") the exception, you will get an uncaught exception error. (Just like in my test session above.) You need to handle the exception where you're using `find`.

Comment: @nolbdnilo thanks again for your help after taking a break from my code I found the error I was calling an exception twice which was causing issues.